# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). NOTHING WORKS

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I feel like I've tried everything. 
user root with empty password doesn't work.

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling mysql. Doesn't work.

Thinking this had something to do with my project in Laravel, I uninstalled and reinstalled it. Started a fresh project. Nope.

Uninstalled reinstalled Homestead. Nope.

Uninstalled reinstalled Vagrant. Nope.

My database config in Laravel looks like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

But when I try:

```
mysql -u homestead -p
```

and 'secret'
I get:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I followed all the steps to this post, and....can you guess? NOPE NOTHING.

[Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) on Laravel 5.2.27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318146/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-using-password-yes-on-laravel)

Please help. I will be happy to provide any more information if I missed anything.

Comment: Less yelling, more patience.

Comment: Unless you've created that user and assigned a password that won't work. If you have previously assigned a password it's saved in the local MySQL database so uninstalling/reinstalling won't reset it unless you explicitly remove the MySQL database as well.

Comment: Are you running the command from homestead or from your local machine?

Comment: you could check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11216911/5695622

Answer (score 1):

I had an old version of Homestead.yaml laying around I think. All I had to do was to change `mysql` to `true` under `features` in my Homestead.yaml. This was `false` for some reason.

Then i did
`vagrant destroy`
`vagrant up`
And everything was working. Hopefully this helps someone

Comment: This has been the problem on more than one occasion for me. I always assume Homestead is MySQL enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this before and honestly sometimes it differs from one person to another, so here is a couple of solutions I know:

**First**:

- Add a password to mysql by running mysqladmin -u root -p pass

But I believe you already tried that so on to the next one,

**Second**

- use this query inside the mysql cli:

  SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('root');

Please notice that this method directly manipulates your database, you just have to start your mysql cli inside your vagrant vm, and type that query as it is inside, then try to login with **root** as the username and **root** as password, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can try reseting the root password by running MySQL in Safe Mode.

1. Stop MySQL:

   `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop`
2. Start it in safe mode:

   `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`

This will be an ongoing command until the process is finished so open another shell/terminal window, and..

3. Log in without a password as root:

   `mysql -u root`
4. Update root (and any other user's) password)

   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
   \q`
5. Restart MySQL in normal mode

   `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`

Reference: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password/

Note: this is pretty much a copy-paste from the reference link. this is pretty standard reset procedure, but just documented better in that guide compared to mysql reference docs.

Comment: Please post the relevant info here.